# Installing python-pip and python3-pip in Docker image

Tags: python, docker, pip, dockerfile

I need to build a Docker image with `python2` and `python3` with ubuntu as base. So I have added below commands to my Dockerfile to install `python2` and `python3`. Along with those, I'm trying to install `python-pip` and `python3-pip`.

```
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        python2 \
        python-pip ; \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        python3 \
        python3-pip ; \
```

When I try to build the above Dockerfile, the `python2`, `python-pip` and `python3` are installing successfully. But when `python3-pip` is installing, it is removing `python-pip`. Do we need both `python-pip` and `python3-pip`? If yes, how can I make the `python3-pip` to not remove `python-pip` package?