# How to install pip for python2 and pip3 for python3 in Ubuntu Docker?

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, pip, python-2.x

How can I install `pip` for `python2` and `pip3` for `python3`. So that when I run `pip --version` it should show `pip 18.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip (python 2.7)` and when I run `pip3 --version`, it should show `pip 18.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.7)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing python-pip and python3-pip in Docker image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76699730/installing-python-pip-and-python3-pip-in-docker-image)

Comment: No. It didn't work.

Comment: I tried to do the same as suggested in another question. But when I'm installing python3-pip, it is removing python-pip.

Comment: Python 2.7 is quite obsolete at this point; do you actually need it?  A Docker image runs only one program and usually contains only that single program's language runtime, so could you use two separate images, one with Python 2.7 and another with a modern Python that gets bug fixes and updates?

Comment: I now also see [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76699730/installing-python-pip-and-python3-pip-in-docker-image); it seems like both are basically asking the same thing?

Comment: What if you install Python3 and python3-pip first, and then Python2 and python-pip? Does it help?